# Can MockProducer and MockConsumer be used with kafkaTemplate producer

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a service which using kafkaTemplate to send the kafka message.

```
@Service
class KafkaProducer(@Autowired val kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, String>) {


final fun sendMessage(msg: String) {
    val abc = kafkaTemplate.send(AppConstants.TOPIC_NAME, "abc", msg)

    abc.whenComplete {
            result, ex ->
        if (ex != null) {
            print("ex occured")
            print(ex.message)
        } else {
            print("sent successfully")
            print(result.producerRecord.value())
        }
    }
}
```

}

For unit test, I am trying to mock this KafkaProducer.

Can i use MockProducer (import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.MockProducer) for this?

```
   @Test
fun verify_test() {
    val mockProducer = MockProducer(true,StringSerializer(), StringSerializer())
    val kafkaProducer = KafkaProducer(mockProducer)

}
```

On trying the above code, i am getting error bcoz KafkaProducer takes argument as KafkaTemplate object, and I am providing MockProducer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using a mock `ProducerFactory`...

```java
@SpringJUnitConfig
class So74993413ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void test(@Autowired KafkaTemplate<String, String> template,
            @Autowired MockProducer<String, String> producer) throws Exception {

        CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = template.send("foo", "bar");
        SendResult<String, String> sendResult = future.get();
//      System.out.println(sendResult);
        List<ProducerRecord<String, String>> history = producer.history();
        assertThat(history).hasSize(1);
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = history.get(0);
        assertThat(record.topic()).isEqualTo("foo");
        assertThat(record.value()).isEqualTo("bar");
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class Config {

        @Bean
        MockProducer<String, String> producer() {
            return new MockProducer<>(true, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer());
        }

        @Bean
        ProducerFactory<String, String> pf (MockProducer producer) {
            return new ProducerFactory<>() {

                @Override
                public Producer<String, String> createProducer() {
                    return producer;
                }

            };
        }

        @Bean
        KafkaTemplate<String, String> template(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
            return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

KafkaTemplate is not a type of Producer. Native Kafka classes cannot be used in place of Spring's - that'd be a reverse dependency.

You would have to mock the template instead since that's what you're actually using. By doing so, it'll bypass any KafkaProducer instance the template used, mock or not.

Comment: You can create a `MockProducerFactory` and inject it into the template; then the template will use the `MockProducer`. Similarly for consumers and listener containers. We should probably add these factories to spring-kafka-test; feel free to open a new feature suggestion.

Comment: @GaryRussell thanks for your input. But could you give an example too please

Comment: See my answer for an example mock producer factory.